# How can I make hyperlink item menu drawer?

Tags: html, android-studio

I have project Android Studio with menu Drawer, and inside of menu drawer have face book item. How can able when I click that item will be hyperlink to open web browser visiting face book.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you need to create a normal item in navigation drawer menu let us say Go to Facebook and in your activity onClick method of navigation menu items paste this code.

```
String url = "http://www.facebook.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: my pleasure buddy.